Assistance with Zoom OAuth Integration in Freshworks App
Our team is building a custom app within the Freshworks suite, and we are currently working on integrating Zoom OAuth. We have followed the documentation and successfully implemented the OAuth token process, allowing us to obtain the token and make third-party calls using the request template.
However, we are facing an issue with signing out of the Zoom app. There doesn't seem to be an option available for signing out, and we need to ensure that users can switch accounts when necessary.
Note: We have seen that Freshworks is already integrated with Zoom, but we require additional features from Zoom, which is why we are using the custom app functionality.
Could you please guide us on how to implement a sign-out functionality for the Zoom integration?
I followed the documentation and successfully integrated the Zoom OAuth process. I expected there to be an option to sign out or revoke the OAuth token, allowing users to switch accounts. However, I couldn't find a method to log out, which is blocking the account-switching functionality.
